# RaphaelJS: Loop through shapes array and onmouseevent select all the other shapes except the one triggered

Tags: javascript, raphael

My title isn't probably really clear so I'll add some explanations. I've created a map using [`RaphaelJS`](http://raphaeljs.com/). I got different regions and I've managed to add different animations/attributes when hovering them.

The main issue I'm facing right now is that when hovering one I'd like that all the other shapes that are not hovered disappear. I could do it easily for many HTML elements by adding a class "hovered" when the event is triggered but this doesnt work with Raphael, or at least I don't know how to apply a class to a shape.

Here is a bit of my code :

```
var regions = {}; // I'm putting all my shapes in there. for example region.myRegion = paper.path();

for (var state in region) {
  region[state].color = "#c6d2ec";
  (function (st, state) {
    st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";

    st[0].onmouseover = function () {
      st.animate({fill: st.color}, 100);
      st.animate({transform: "s1.3"}, 100);
      paper.safari();

    };

    st[0].onmouseout = function () {
      st.animate({fill: "#e5e5e5"}, 300);
      st.animate({transform: "s1"}, 100);
      paper.safari();

    };
  })(region[state], state);
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint of how I could achieve this? Thanks.